# Can not read external hard disk with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: hard-drive

I have 2TB WD external hard disk with (NTFS) format.
I try to read it with Ubuntu 14.04 without success.
Also tried to install NTFS-3g, but still not working

I have a lot of data store inside. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem earlier on and tried a few commands so I don't know which one actually did it but here is a list from my terminal history.

```
sudo e2fsck -y /dev/sda1 
/dev/sda1 /media ntfs -ro 
chmod /dev/sda1 -r 
/dev/sda1 -r-w 
sudo fdisk -lu 
/dev/sda1 sodu fdisk -lu
```

Please note that some commands aren't real, just a mixture of commands I tried to run. In any case all of them did nothing until I restarted my PC.

Also take note to update your apt data with the cmd:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post the error messages...
And ntfs3g is pre installed in ubuntu...

So the Main Problem should be a unsafe unplug vor umount.
If this is your Problem you can See messages regarding that in your logs.
You can override that or just Connect und eject the drive once in Windows...

Perhaps this helps: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)